# Do Design Patterns matter in Data Driven programs?

Tags: java, xml, design-patterns, xml-parsing

I have done my research and still cannot find an answer to this question.

There are some links that I think kind of explain it, but still no clear answer.

Also there is a similar question in stackoverflow but the answers are not really fulfilling.

Thoughts?

http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/courses/cs106a/handouts/56-data-driven-programs.pdf

Last link kind of explains it, but ...

http://gamesfromwithin.com/data-oriented-design

Comment: Having read through the first couple of pages of that hand-out: "Data-Driven Programming" sounds like regular programming to me.  So all design patterns should apply.  I don't see anything special or different in that teacher's handout, any different solution would be suspect.

Comment: Read the second link

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Design Patterns are nothing more than some generalised solution for a problem that is encountered over and over. They are not some OOP silver bullet that will make your program perfect.

The design patterns used may differ between programming paradigms, but there will always be common problems that can be solved by a general solution.